# MySQL to read relational algebra?

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra

I'm trying to get MySQL to take a relational algebra input but it will not accept projections and so forth symbols.

For example

```
Πstarter, ender, pointsStarter, pointsEnder, debatedate (contest)
```

I get errors that the projection is not accepted.

I have

```
(Πstarter, ender, pointsStarter, pointsEnder, debatedate(σpointsStarter>=pointsEnder(Contest))) |>
```

Contest.starter=Debater.name (σclub=’Plato’(Debater))

MySQL will not accept it, thoughts?

Comment: That's akin to spelling English sentences in Cyrilic script; the meaning doesn't change, but the set of receivers who will understand it changes dramatically.

Comment: Do you know of any way I can test to see if the RA does work against the table I have?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Valid MySQL input is in the form of [SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html) queries, not relational algebra expressions. Although, if it did, that would be quite interesting.

Edit: [RA](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra/) a piece of Java software that converts relational algebra into SQL queries, if you'd like to go down that path.

Comment: Is there anyway I can test the RA against the tables I have to see if it works?

Comment: Based on the linked page, it looks like you can just configure the settings for your MySQL database and run the jar file. It seems to have a command line interface. I haven't used it myself, but it's something that came up that I thought might be worthwhile to note.